# How to increase pixels size of a Bitmap

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I want to know if it's possible to modify bitmap pixels by pixels. I'm not asking for changing bitmap size/scale. What I'm looking for is that I want to increase size of all or some specific pixels of a bitmap.

I tried this

```
Thread(Runnable {
         val newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.width * 4,
                 bitmap.height * 4, true);

         for (x in 0 until bitmap.getWidth()) {
             for (y in 0 until bitmap.getHeight()) {

                 val pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                 val redValue = Color.red(pixel)
                 val blueValue = Color.blue(pixel)
                 val greenValue = Color.green(pixel)

                 newBitmap.setPixel(x * 4, y * 4, Color.rgb(redValue, greenValue, blueValue))

             }
         }

         runOnUiThread({ imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap) })

     }).start()
```

But it has no effect on the bitmap. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what you mean by `increase size of all or some specific pixels`? Pixel size is always 1 pixel, it is not modifiable. Probably you want to color surrounding pixels in the same color as the pixel you choose?

Comment: I want to make pixel appear larger so that it has a pixelated/mosaic  effect.

Comment: Probably you want to color surrounding pixels in the same color as the pixel you choose. That's a nice suggestion. Any ideas?

Comment: to color all pixels around, do `setPixel` for x+1 y+1, x+1 y, x y+1, etc. coordinates

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pixelate just a part of your bitmap, then you could create a `Bitmap` of the part which you wish to edit, perform changes on the new bitmap and then overlay the changed bitmap on top of the original bitmap.

So for example, you could pixelate a portion of a `Bitmap` by doing something along the following lines,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Bitmap originalBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawabledroid)).getBitmap();
    // Pixelate just the top half
    int x = 0, y = 0, width = originalBitmap.getWidth(), height = originalBitmap.getHeight()/2;
    //Or pixelate a rectangle in the middle
    //int x = originalBitmap.getWidth()/2 - 50, y = originalBitmap.getHeight()/2 - 50, width = 100, height = 100;

    //Get bitmap with region you want to pixelate
    Bitmap original = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, x,y,width,height);

    int normalWidth = original.getWidth(), normalHeight = original.getHeight();
    int smallWidth = normalWidth/15, smallHeight = normalHeight/15;

    Bitmap small = getResizedBitmap(original, smallWidth, smallHeight);
    Bitmap pixelated = getResizedBitmap(small, normalWidth, normalHeight);

    //Overlay the pixelated bitmap on top of the original
    Bitmap overlayed = overlayBitmaps(originalBitmap, pixelated,x,y, width, height);
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
}

public static Bitmap overlayBitmaps(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    //If you know the background in transparent or any specific color
    //Then you can color the region before overlaying the pixelated bitmap
    Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawRect(x,y, x+width,y+height, mPaint);
    //Overlay the pixelated bitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, x, y, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```